# How to remove an Eclipse project from a Working Set?

Tags: java, eclipse, working-set

I had to shutdown Eclipse ungracefully (killing the pid itself) and when I restarted it, all of my projects now show up in Package Explorer as belonging to a Working Set called *Other Projects*. I'm afraid that if I delete *Other Projects* I'll also delete all the projects it contains.

I need to simply remove all my projects from this working set and then delete the working set once it is empty, but the Eclipse manual and Google have turned up nothing. Ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try running eclipse with the `-clean` argument? Have you tried right clicking -> remove from Working Set, or switching workspaces?

Comment: did you try right click on your project and "assign working sets" then deselect from here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, projects that aren't assigned to any Working Set show up under "*Other Projects*" in the Package Explorer. If you change Top Level Elements to show Projects instead of Working Sets, it should disappear.

Comment: You are my new favorite superhero.

Comment: Thanks this was killing me